# Facebook Error (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

Tags: c#, facebook

I have the following:

```
         // my facebook page
        var pageId = facebookPageId;

        var app = new FacebookClient();
        dynamic fbResult = app.Get("oauth/access_token", new {
            client_id = facebookAppId,
            client_secret = facebookAppSecret,
            grant_type = "client_credentials"
        });
        app.AccessToken = fbResult.access_token;

        dynamic messagePost = new ExpandoObject();
        messagePost.access_token = app.AccessToken;
        messagePost.link = "www.google.com";
        messagePost.name = "some name";
        messagePost.caption = "{test actor} " + "Test message"; //<---{*actor*} is the user (i.e.: Aaron)
        messagePost.description = "Test description";

        try {
            var result = app.Post("/" + pageId + "/feed", messagePost);
        } catch (FacebookOAuthException ex) {
            var test = ex;
        } catch (FacebookApiException ex) {
            var test = ex;
        }
```

Yet I always get `(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action` as a result.  What am I doing wrong?  It's a page that I own - but I don't see how to go about granting POST permissions to my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user needs `publish_actions` permissions.
Implement a login dialog for the user to grant `publish_actions`

You are using an application access token.

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/feed#publish

---

To grant permissions via the Graph API Explorer

Select your app from the dropdown menu

[image: Select application]

Then select the permission by clicking "Get Access Token" then selecting `publish_actions` under *Extended Permissions*, and finally click get token.

[image: Get Access Token]

Comment: Do you know how I can implement this with code only (no dialog)?  This is a console app.

Comment: @user666 not possible. That defeats the purpose of the dialog if you can bypass it. All Facebook login by a user must be done manually. I f this is for personal user you can manually grant the permission via the Graph API Explorer Tool.

Comment: Yes, I only need to set this permission for my account so that I can use my app to post to my page.  I see the API explorer - what do I need to do to get this permission sorted out?  Apologies, I'm just a little lost!

Comment: Awesome!  This is now working.  If I look at my page, I don't see the post though.  I don't even see it in the sidebar of the page... I only see it if I click the "Posts to Page" link in the sidebar and look at the popup.  Any thoughts on why the posts aren't showing up on the wall?

Comment: @user666 it sounds like you as a user (personal profile) are posting to a page (fan page). To post as the page you need to get a page access token by granting yourself manage_pages permission and getting the page token from an API call to `/me/accounts` (using the user token with the last call)

Comment: Ok great, I'll give it a shot.  Thanks again.  I *may* end up posting another question :/

Comment: in case you have a few more minutes :P  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27476515/posting-to-page-as-page-using-c-sharp-facebook