# Posting to Page as Page using C# (Facebook)

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've made some progress thanks to this page: [Facebook Error (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27476052/facebook-error-200-the-user-hasnt-authorized-the-application-to-perform-this/27476262?noredirect=1#comment43387069_27476262)

However, I'm now lost when it comes to posting as a page. From the comments, I see that I need to

> ... get a page access token by granting yourself manage_pages permission and getting the page token from an API call to /me/accounts (using the user token with the last call)

I've gone and granted myself `manage_pages` permission but how do I make an API call to `/me/accounts` to get the page token?  And once I get the page token, do I just simply use that token instead and leave my code as it stands?

Code below:

```
        var pageId = facebookPageId;

        var app = new FacebookClient();
        app.AccessToken = facebookAccessToken; // copied from Graph Explorer

        dynamic messagePost = new ExpandoObject();
        messagePost.access_token = facebookAccessToken; // copied from Graph Explorer
        messagePost.link = "www.google.com";
        messagePost.name = "some name";
        messagePost.caption = "{test actor} " + "Test message"; //<---{*actor*} is the user (i.e.: Aaron)
        messagePost.description = "Test description";

        try {
            var result = app.Post("/" + pageId + "/feed", messagePost);
        } catch (FacebookOAuthException ex) {
            var test = ex;
        } catch (FacebookApiException ex) {
            var test = ex;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've gone and granted myself manage_pages permission but how do I make an API call to /me/accounts to get the page token?

You use the API, I'm assuming there is an equivalent call in the C# SDK for `app.Post` as `app.Get`. Seeing that this is a personal app, you can just use the developer tool again, select your app from the dropdown, grant yourself `manage_pages` permissions then call `/me/accounts`

[image: Page Tokens]

The page token for your page should be there in the result.

You can also directly get it via a call to `PAGE_ID?fields=access_token`

[image: Specific Page Token]

Comment: New question in case you have a moment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583034/posting-to-page-as-page-using-c-sharp-token-expiring